# Can an Iterable<? extends String> ever contain anything other than Strings?

Tags: java, generics

I am quite new to Java, it seems to me that

```
Iterable<? extends String>
```

can only ever be an

```
Iterable<String>
```

since String is final, and cannot be derived from.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree to that.

Comment: Yep! That is correct.

Comment: You could still use that syntax to prevent adding to the iterable, i.e. you know that it will contain strings but the compiler will throw an error if you try to add something (since the compiler isn't as smart as you and doesn't know that only strings will be possible anyways ;) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is true and valid, not much to add to it.

So I'll anticipate the next question (as I did in my comment, just as an answer for formatting reasons): why would one use `Iterable<? extends String>` if the only possible definition would be `Iterable<String>`?

To be honest: with `Iterable` you don't have any methods that add anything so it wouldn't make much sense. But lets replace `Iterable` with `List`.

What's the difference between `List<? extends String>` and `List<String>`?

With `List<String>` the compiler knows that the list is meant to contain `String` objects and thus it would allow you to call `add("newStringLiteral")`.

But with `List<? extends String>` the compiler isn't so sure anymore. Of course we can't extend `String` but the compiler doesn't check that and hence would have to assume it were possible.

Now let's pretend we were able to write a class `SpecialString extends String`. If we'd call `List<? extends String> l = new ArrayList<SpecialString>()` we'd want to restrict the list to only contain `SpecialString` objects. But the compiler only sees `List<? extends String>` so it assumes there might be a restriction on the actual type and thus considers  `add("newStringLiteral")` to be an error.

So using `List<? extend String>` would basically make the parameter a list you can't add anything to (just read and remove).

Comment: A key part of your logic that you didn't include is that a non-final String is bytecode-compatible as a replacement for the current String class (e.g. if compile-time used the normal String class but it was replaced by a non-final one at runtime).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers already explained that your assumption regarding `? extends String` is correct. But there is a catch when you ask

> Can an `Iterable<? extends String>` ever contain anything other than
>   Strings?

You can easily construct a `Iterable<String>` which can contain any object, not just Strings:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add(Boolean.TRUE);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Iterable<String> i = a; 

Object elem = i.iterator().next();
assert elem == Boolean.TRUE;
```

Comment: +(int)(PI/3) for being the only one here noticing the fact that due to type erasure the generic contract in Java is **always** a weak (*should*), not a strong (*must*) contract **unless** you use a [runtime-checked class-safe derivative of the collection](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ004) (but then you lose the generic information for nested generics *doh!*).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, true. The only valid Object will be String.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, String cannot be extended as it is final so the statement

```
Iterable<? extends String>
```

Doesn't make a huge amount of sense.

Answer (score 0):

As `string` is a final class, it is true.